# GDG Roll In Error

Tags: mainframe

While executing one Proc, I am geting a 'GDG Roll In Error'. The Error Message says `'IGD07001I GDG ROLL IN ERROR -RETURN CODE 20 REASON CODE 0 MODULE IGG0CLEG'`. The proc is supposed to create 19 generations of a GDG. This error occurs after creating first 6 Generatons. The parameters of the GDG are `Limit=100, NOEMPTY,SCRATCH`. What could be the reason.?
 Experts, Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look up [IGD07001I](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=messages-igd07001i) it says, among other things, to look at [IDC3009I](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=messages-idc3009i) for an explanation of the return and reason codes.  For return code 20 reason code 0, IDC3009I says

> RETURN CODE 20  Explanation: There is insufficient space in the
> catalog to perform the requested update or addition.
>
> The catalog cannot be extended for one of the following reasons:
>
> - There is no more space on the volume on which the catalog resides
> - The maximum number of extents has been reached
> - The catalog has reached the 4GB limit
> - There is not enough contiguous space on the volume (required when the catalog's secondary allocation is defined in tracks).
>
> Programmer Response: Scratch unneeded data sets from the volume.
> Delete all unnecessary entries from the catalog. The catalog may need
> to be reallocated and rebuilt if these steps do not resolve the space
> shortage.

I suggest contacting your DFSMS Administrator.  I also suggest bookmarking the [z/OS documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos) for your version/release.

Comment: Spot on. I assume this is not Production, but it is poor storage-management to allow any catalog to fill. The messages are easy to look up, with IBM LookAt. Even on your Mobile Phone...